# my for loop doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).onload(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <max; i++) {
        if(pi[i]===undefined||pi[i]===null||pi[i]==0){
            pi[i]=1;
        }
    }
});
alert('hello');
```

I have jQuery installed and all the variables are set earlier on in the code, but anything after the for loop doesn't work such as the alert('hello'). If anyone cans see something wrong with this please tell me.

edit

```
var max=438;
localStorage.setItem('max', max);
var pi=[];
pi=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pi'));
var i=localStorage.getItem('i');
var url1=Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
var url2=Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
if(url1==url2){

url2=url2+2;
if(url2>max){
    url2=url2-max;
}
}
document.getElementById('imgimg1').src='../img/'+url1+'.gif';
document.getElementById('imgimg2').src='../img/'+url2+'.gif';
var v1=url1-1;
var v2=url2-1;
function vote1() {
    pi[v1]=pi[v1]+(pi[v2]/pi[v1]);
    localStorage.setItem('pi',JSON.stringify(pi));
    location.reload();
}
function vote2() {
    pi[v2]=pi[v2]+(pi[v1]/pi[v2]);
    localStorage.setItem('pi',JSON.stringify(pi));
    location.reload();
}
$(document).load(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <max; i++) {
        if(pi[i]===undefined||pi[i]===null||pi[i]==0){
            pi[i]=1;
        }
    }
});
alert(pi);
```

this is the full code

Comment: Does `max` have a value?

Comment: `onload` is not a valid jQuery method. If you open the developer tools in your browser and look at the console you'll find an error stating this fact.

Comment: The `alert` is not after the for loop. The loop only gets executed asynchronously after the document loaded. The alert should have already been shown by then.

Comment: where is array declared and where is max declared and have you added jquery library as reference ?

Comment: Better use `$(document).ready(function(){for..});`

Comment: Check your console. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: max and the array are declared at the beginning of the javascript file.

Comment: I changed .onload to .ready and alert('hello') to alert(pi) and the pop up said null even though this for loop should save the pi array several numbers

Comment: Are array's elements set to 1 without the if statement ?

Comment: How `pi` is initialized and where ? If it writes 'null' so alert() may not have access to it.

Comment: its set at the beginning of the javascript file so alert() should have acces

Comment: You really should post all the relevant code if you want help. People have to speculate when you don't.

Comment: @Jasper is right, add the code where variables are initialized please

Comment: I just added it hope this will help

Comment: Checkout my (edited) answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
/* assuming this */
var max = 4; // for example
var pi = [0, 0, 0, 0];
/* end assuming this */

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if(pi && pi[i] && pi[i] < 0) {
            pi[i] = -1;
        } else {
            pi[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(pi));
});
```

It should write *'[1, 1, 1, 1]'*

**[EDIT]**

Regarding your entire code, why do you need to loop after document ready ?

Why not init `pi` like that:

```
var max=438;
localStorage.setItem('max', max);
var pi=[];
pi=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pi'));
for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    pi[i] = 1;
}
[...]
```

Comment: I don't know why I was using document ready, but when i take away the document ready the alert() doesn't work. Also I need the if pi[i] is not set because I am using the array as a data base of numbers and need to be able to increase the number of values in the array while not affecting those already set, as they will change with the vote functions.

Comment: you can see the project at https://preview.c9users.io/ibricchi/memer/images/index.html

Comment: `localStorage` contains `{max: "438", length: 1}` that's why `localStorage.getItem('pi')` is null and so does `pi`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all variables are set correctly, your code should be:

```
$(document).load(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <max; i++) {
        if(pi[i]===undefined||pi[i]===null||pi[i]==0){
            pi[i]=1;
        }
    }
    alert('hello');
});
```

Maybe this will help, although, I do not know what you are setting these variables to. Please note that instead of document load, I am using the jquery ready event.

```html
<div id="message"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var max = 100;
  var pi = [];
  
  $(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <max; i++) {
        if(pi[i]===undefined||pi[i]===null||pi[i]==0){
            pi[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    $('#message').text(pi.length);
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you but if I alert pi after this it returns null rather than an array of 400 ones (max is set to 400)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).onload(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <max; i++) {
        if(typeof pi[i]==="undefined"||pi[i]===null||pi[i]==0){
            pi[i]=1;
        }
    }
});
alert('hello');
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have "max" set to some positive number. 
I think the problem is that you coded
  *$(document).**onload**(...*
when you should have coded
  *$(document).**ready**(...*
Hope that helps!
PK

Comment: I changed it to ready but if I alert pi it returns null rather than an array of 400 ones (max is set to 400)