# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null on for loop

Tags: javascript

```
var max=438;
localStorage.setItem('max', max);
var pi=[];
pi=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pi'));
var i=localStorage.getItem('i');
var url1=Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
var url2=Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
if(url1==url2){
    url2=url2+2;
    if(url2>max){
        url2=url2-max;
    }
}
document.getElementById('imgimg1').src='../img/'+url1+'.gif';
document.getElementById('imgimg2').src='../img/'+url2+'.gif';
var v1=url1-1;
var v2=url2-1;
function vote1() {
    pi[v1]=pi[v1]+(pi[v2]/pi[v1]);
    localStorage.setItem('pi',JSON.stringify(pi));
    location.reload();
}
function vote2() {
    pi[v2]=pi[v2]+(pi[v1]/pi[v2]);
    localStorage.setItem('pi',JSON.stringify(pi));
    location.reload();
}
for (var i = 0; i <max; i++) {
    if(pi[i]==null){
        pi.push(1);
    }
}
```

I keep on getting TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null on my for loop at the end even though it seems to be right to me. Any help I could get to solve this would be a great help. I'm trying to use this array as a database changed by the vote functions, and need to be able to increase the available array slots whenever I change the value of max.

Comment: Is the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921347/my-for-loop-doesnt-work-and-i-dont-know-why) ?

Comment: That error means that `JSON.parse()` is returnning `null`. Do you have anything in the `pi` element of `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot read property '0' of null on my for loop at the end even though it seems to be right to me.

This means that `pi` does not have a property `0`. Try logging the value of pi (in each loop?) to console or use debugger.